# AWK (or similar) - change 2 lines below the matching pattern

Tags: parsing, awk, scripting, insert

I have a problem that I think it's easiest to solve with awk but I wrapped my head around it.
Inside a file I have repeating output like this:

```
....
  Name="BgpIpv4RouteConfig_XXX">
          <Ipv4NetworkBlock id="13726"
           StartIpList="x.y.z.t"
           PrefixLength="30"
           NetworkCount="10000"
... other output
```

then this block will repeat.

a)I want to match on BGPIpv4Route.*, then skip 2 lines (the "n" keyword of awk), then when reaching Prefix Length:
- either replace it with random (25,30)
or
- better but I guess harder (no idea came to mind for keeping track of what was used and looping among /25../30) -> first occurrence /25, second one /26...till /30, then rollback to /25

b) then next line with NetworkCount depending on the new value of PrefixCount calculate it as 65536 / 2^(32-Prefix Count)

eg: if PrefixCount on this occurrence was replaced with /25, then NetworkCount on the line following it = 65536 / 2 ^ 7 = 65536 / 128 = 512

I found some examples with inserting/changing a line after one that matched (or with a counter variable X lines below the match) but I got a bit confused with the value generation part and also with the changing of two lines where one is depending on the other.
Not sure I made any sense...my head is a bit overwhelmed with what I'm finding everywhere right now.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should do

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {q="\""; FS=OFS="="; n=split("25=26=27=28=29=30",ps)}
       /BgpIpv4Route/ {c=c%n+1}
       /PrefixLength/ {$2=q ps[c] q}
       /NetworkCount/ {$2=q 65536/2^(32-ps[c]) q}1' file
```

perhaps minimize computation by changing to `2^(ps[c]-16)`

If there are free standing PrefixLength and NetworkCount attributes perhaps you need to qualify them for each BgpIpv4Route context.

Comment: Thanks!  
Works like a charm. I can't believe it was so straightforward.   
I learned something new.

Comment: Was thinking now...this would also cause changes in case it finds a PrefixLength entry without having a preceeding BgpIpv4Route one, no?
Is there any way to make it a constraint to replace PrefixLength and NetworkCount only if it finds them to be the 3rd and 4th line after the BgpIpv4Route match?

Comment: Yes, record the line number with context switch and compare in addition to pattern match.